# Django-piston. How to serialize to JSON objects that are not Model subclasses?

Tags: json, django, django-piston

I'm working with django + piston and so far created a few urls that are returning my django models in JSON quite well. I didn't even have to specify an emitter, the JSON serialization is done automagically.

Now I need to return a JSON serialized object that does not extend Django Model class. If I return its value, piston returns the __ str __ value, even if I add the JSON emitter nothing happens. I don't want to add the JSON serialization in the __ str __ method since it wouldn't be correct.
What's the correct approach for this?

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend using http://tastypieapi.org/ over Piston.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) package to do this.

Snippet:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
```

If you're looking to create this in the context of django view, you'll want to make sure you're sending back the right content type.  That is,

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse(your_json_string, mimetype='application/json')
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily work for all types in general.  It's usually a good idea to construct a `dict` containing exactly what you want to return, then serialize it.